# Multiple calls with dependencies redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

**Question:**

I use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and I want to receive posts. To receive posts I need to get users. So I have doubts about my thunk, Is it right to get all the data in one thunk, if not how to split it into two thunks?

**Thunk example:**

```
export default group_id => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const users = await API.get(`/users?group_id=${group_id}`) // get users
    const posts = await axios.all([...getPosts(users)]) // get all posts by user ids
    dispatch(loadUsersAction(users))
    dispatch(loadPostsAction(posts))
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not a middleware though but a thunk. Middleware is something you pass to `applyMiddleware`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several approaches depending of your requirements.

If the purpose is to load, initially users, and then their post, i would call firstly `/users`, and then dispatch another action creator to get their `/posts`.
Because getting it all together would make your users waiting longer for something to change in the UI (ex: loading spinner), thus i would split these in two separate actions.

```js
export function getUsers(group_id) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const users = await API.get(`/users?group_id=${group_id}`); 
    dispatch(loadUsersAction(users));
    return users;
  };
};

export function getPostForGroupUsers (group_id) => {
  return async dispatch => {       
    const users = await dispatch(getUsers(group_id));
    const posts = await axios.all([...getPosts(users)]);
    dispatch(loadPostsAction(posts));
    return posts;
  }
}

// or just call users, dispatch and get them from store

export function getPostForAllUsers  () => {
  return async dispatch => {       
    // this depends on your implementation
    const users = getFromReduxStore('users');
    const posts = await axios.all([...getPosts(users)]);
    dispatch(loadPostsAction(posts));
    return posts;
  }
}
```

Maybe you can provide more details of your case, I then could give more precise response.

Comment: you are awaiting thunk getUsers function instead of dispatching it in getPostForGroupUsers

Comment: @HassanGilak is correct, should be `await dispatch(getUsers(group_id))`

Comment: One thing to add, I'm personal a fan of thunks while your intertwining isn't complex, but once you get to this kind of level, I'd advocate more heavily for a side  library.